Postman: Before executing a request, how do I remove a cookie
In pre-request script , I want to clear this cookie named as accesstoken, so that I can execute my request without this cookie to be passed in the header for the request,
how do I do that ?
I have tried:
console.log("Testing request: Clearing the cookie");
pm.cookies.clear();
console.log("Value of cookie is "+ pm.cookies)

But it is not working.
When I send a request, the cookie is present, which is not what I want.
Moreover, how do I print value of one cookie?


Have you added that domain to the Allowlist? https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/response-data/cookies/#script-with-cookies

its working, my next question is how to add domain to allowlist programatically in pre-request script ? since I want to avoid manual intervention during testing

Actually i found what i wanted --> To turn off sending cookies with a request, select the request's Settings tab, then select Disable cookie jar. from https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/response-data/cookies/#programmatic-access-of-cookies
